# Find a minimal subspace $W_{\alpha}$ in $V$ for a given $\alpha \in \bigwedge^{p}(V)$ for which $\alpha \in \bigwedge^{p}(W_{\alpha}).$

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, multilinear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space of dimension $n$, and $1\leq p \leq n$, show that for every $\alpha \in \bigwedge^{p}(V)$ there exists a minimal subspace $W_{\alpha}$ in $V$ such that $\alpha \in \bigwedge^{p}(W_{\alpha})$. I was thinking about using induction, maybe contracting $\alpha$ along some vectors could be of help.

Comment: If you really mean just *minimal*, this is trivial: just take $W$ of minimal dimension among all subspaces such that $\alpha\in\bigwedge^p(W)$.  Much less trivial would be to ask for a *least* such subspace, i.e. such a subspace which contains all other such subspaces.

Comment: @EricWofsey I think the exercise mean least. The exercise is proposed in an Italian book and the adjective used for the subspace is 'minimo'.

Comment: @EricWofsey anyway thanks for your answer, one must first think about the trivial solutions!